# Error Message - Cannot login to Wordpress

Tags: errors, headers

I am getting this error message and cannot log in to wordpress anymore. Can someone please help:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/customer/www/anzaed.org.au/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bbp-style-pack/includes/settings_subscriptions_management.php:120) in /home/customer/www/anzaed.org.au/public_html/wp-content/plugins/lifterlms/includes/functions/llms-functions-wrappers.php on line 157

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message - it's the 'bbp-style-pack' plugin.

Temporarily rename that plugin folder (in the wp-content/plugins folder) to disable it. Then, after you log in as admin, check the plugin version to see if it is current. It current, delete the plugin - you don't need that hassle.